# How do I register a JWT token expired event with AngularFire? (AngularFire Custom Authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, jwt

**How do I register a JWT token expired event with AngularFire?**

Right now I have my Rails server sending a JWT to the AngularJS client, which is set to expire in 60 seconds. I'm connecting to Firebase on my client successfully. After 60 seconds, it expires and I get a **"FIREBASE WARNING: auth() was canceled: Auth token is expired."** message in my browser console.

**It is not clear to me what to watch for this event. My goal would be to call my server for a new token when my current one expires.**

client code snippet: here is me initializing a firebase obj and watching a url

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);

// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
var authDataCallback = function (authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out", authData);
  }
}

// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

var authHandler = function(error, authData) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);


    var firebaseBal = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

    // update balance when val changes
    firebaseWatch = firebaseBal.$watch(function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.balance = firebaseBal.$value;
    });
  }
}

// Authenticate users with a custom Firebase token
ref.authWithCustomToken(Auth.firebaseToken(), authHandler);
```

server code snippet (I use firebase-token-generator to generate my JWT token):

```
generator = Firebase::FirebaseTokenGenerator.new(secret);

payload = { :uid => "123" }

# expired in a minute, for testing
expires = Time.now.to_i + (60*1)
options = {:expires => expires}

token = generator.create_token(payload, options)

// this is then sent to the client
```

Comment: This is cross-posted from an open GitHub issue which already has a discussion going. Let's keep the discussion there. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/514

Comment: Apologies - I posted this before I heard back from you and then left the office. Glad to hear things are in the works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem to be solved soon, see GitHub issue - https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/514

> This GitHub issue exists for the exact reason to help you accomplish
>   what you want to accomplish :) The short answer is that we don't
>   really support this that well right now.
>
> For the time being, you will have to use $extendFactory() and put your
>   logic in the $$error()method. Here are the slim docs on that. The
>   $$error() method will fire once authentication fails due to token
>   expiry or security rules.
>
> You should see improvements in this area in the coming weeks and this
>   is tagged for the 1.0.0 release.

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);

var authHandler = function(error, authData) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);

    // create a factory to pass into $firebase
    var timeoutErrorFactory = $FirebaseObject.$extendFactory({            
      $$error: function(data) {
        // TODO: not sure if super needs to be applied
        // var err = $FirebaseObject.prototype.$$error.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('firebase timeout error cleanup', data.code);

        // TODO: call server for a new token
      }
    });

    // create an instance which uses the customized factory
    firebaseBal = $firebase(ref, {objectFactory: timeoutErrorFactory}).$asObject();

    // update balance when val changes
    firebaseWatch = firebaseBal.$watch(function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.balance = firebaseBal.$value;
    });
  }
}

// Authenticate users with a custom Firebase token
ref.authWithCustomToken(Auth.firebaseToken(), authHandler);
```

Comment: Please either post the solution here too or close the question. Link-only answers are not considered acceptable on StackOverflow.